# how to sync videos from PC hard disk to iPhone with itunes?

Tags: itunes, iphone

I don't know how to sync videos using itunes, it is appreciated if you tell step by step to get videos from pc to iphone.
IOS version is : 7.0.4
itunes version : 12.0.1.26
thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have the video's you want to sync to your iPhone allready in iTunes. When not, you can drag the video's into itunes.

Connect you device with the lightning/30-pins cable to your pc and open iTunes if it doesn't pop up automatically.

- At the upper left corner there should be a small iPhone/iPad icon. Click on the icon to view more information about it.
- In the left panel is a menu called video (or something like that)
- check the checkbox that you want to sync video's with your device. When the video's are correctly loaded into iTunes they should popup here.
- select the video('s) you want to have on your device.
- in the lower right corner click on apply/sync (if i'm right)

This will start syncing the video's from iTunes to your device.

When i'm right the video's can be found in the app called "video's".